# Make a matrix invertible

Tags: linear-algebra

> Suppose that $ A $ is $n \times n $ matrix with a 1-dimensional null-space. Show that we can choose vectors $u$ and $v$ so that the linear transformation
>   \begin{equation}
> B = A + u \otimes v^t
> \end{equation}
>   is invertible. Here $ u \otimes v^t x := \langle x, v \rangle u$. What condition must $ u $ and $ v $ satisfy to for this to be true?

---

The first question is easy - we can take $ u \in ImA^⊥,\  v \in KerA$ (both non-zero), then for any $ x \neq \vec{0}$ holds 
\begin{equation}
Bx = Ax + \langle x, v \rangle u,
\end{equation}

where $ Ax \in ImA, \langle x, v \rangle u \in ImA^⊥ $, and therefore $ Bx = \vec{0} $ if and only if both $ Ax $ and $ \langle x, v \rangle $are zero, which is impossible. Therefore $  dim\ KerB = 0$ and $ B $ is invertible. What about the second question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $u \in \mathrm{Im}\ A$, then the range of $B$ is not onto, and hence $B$ is not invertible. If $v \in (\mathrm{Ker}\ A)^\perp$, then $B$ still has non-trivial null space, and hence is also not invertible. Thus, your characterization of how to choose the vectors in the first question is (almost) complete.
So $u$ just needs some component not in the image/column space of $A$, and $v$ needs to have some component in the kernel/null space of $A$.
($u \in \overline{\mathrm{Im}\ A}$, $v \in \overline{\mathrm{Ker}\ A^\perp}$)